# If $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) $ and $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ do not exist, can $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)g(x)$ exist?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I know that $\lim_{x \to a}(f(x)+g(x))$ can exist, but I am not sure that $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)g(x)$ can also exist. Can anyone give me a hint?

There are a lot of cool answers now, and I do appreciate your hints!
This is my example (Of course, I got inspiration from @Jean-Pierre Merx): $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is irrational, $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is rational. $g(x)$ is the converse.

Answer (score 3):

Just take $f(x)=2+\sin x$ and $g(x)=\frac1{2+\sin x}$ for $x\to+\infty$.

Comment: Probably should use $f(x) =2+\sin x, g(x) = 1/(2+\sin x)$ or something, otherwise $g$ not well defined at points.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I'm going to edit!

Answer (score 2):

$0$ on the right and $1$ on the left for $f$ and the converse for $g$.